# String and for (Selenium)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

how to put the Ordernumber String on the sendkey. Thank you
heres my code:

```
String[] Ordernumber = {"21779", "21780", "21781"};
for (int i=0;i<Ordernumber.length;i++) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("txt_searchExistOrder"))).sendKeys(Ordernumber["6"]);
    System.out.println("Proceed GRC Smoke Testing");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: String[] Ordernumber = {"21779", "21780", "21781"}
for (int i=0;i<Ordernumber.length;i++) {
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("txt_searchExistOrder"))).sendKeys("6");
  System.out.println("Proceed GRC Smoke Testing");
  Thread.sleep(5000);

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this does not relate to selenium. It is just looping.

```
String[] Ordernumber = {"21779", "21780", "21781"};
for (int i=0;i<Ordernumber.length;i++) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("txt_searchExistOrder"))).sendKeys(Ordernumber[i]);
    System.out.println("Proceed GRC Smoke Testing");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: @iancastillio Could you answer your question and then accept it? So this question will be marked as ‘Answered’.